# Javascript error handling is not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to catch Ajax error using error handling try/catch but it's not working. Here's my code:

```
var ajaxrequest=null
if (window.ActiveXObject){ 
 try {
  ajaxrequest=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
 } 
 catch {
  try{
   ajaxrequest=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
  } //end inner try
  catch {
   alert("NOT WORKING!!")
  } //end inner catch
 } //end outer catch
}
else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
 ajaxrequest=new XMLHttpRequest()

ajaxrequest.open('GET', 'inventory.php', true) //do something with request
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Perhaps it's just not throwing an exception...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the parameter to catch. It should be catch(ex). Here's the fix:

```
if (window.ActiveXObject){ 
 try {
  ajaxrequest=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
 } 
 catch (ex){
  try{
   ajaxrequest=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
  } //end inner try
  catch (ex){
   alert("NOT WORKING!!")
  } //end inner catch
 } //end outer catch
}
```

Comment: That's it! I really need to get some more sleep! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The usage of catch clause w/o any parameters causes `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`. The proper way to catch exceptions looks like this:

```
try {
    // some code which probably causes exception
} catch(e) {
    // do something with the exception
}
```

Check out the documentation on [exception handling in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch).